Can you help me with the best translation of good mother or mother's way
I am hoping youcan help me. I am working ona project and I am trying to understand how to put a phrase together with the best translation of "good mother" or "mother's way" in Latin. I have found several literal translations but I want to make it makes sense grammatically, etc.
Phrases I have come across:
Bona mater/matris/matri
Via mater/matris
summa mater
Which if any are the best translation. Also if there is a phrase that I have not listed, please do share your recommendations.
Thank you for your time and consideration.

Bona mater means good mother. Via matris means mother's way. Summa mater means highest mother.

Some more context would be useful.
Do you mean "Mother's way" like in "We're doing it her way"?
Because then via is best used together with ratio: Matris viā et ratione 
normally "via" means "street" but it can be used in this figurative manner also (this use is rare, though).
